# Problem removing sub category from permalink URL of blog post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, categories, blogs, slug

I'm using this solution to remove sub-categories from the url on my blog posts: 
[Remove sub category slug from permalink URL of blog post and custom post type in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532157/remove-sub-category-slug-from-permalink-url-of-blog-post-and-custom-post-type-in)

```
add_filter('post_link','custom_post_type_link',10,3); 

function custom_post_type_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
if (!gettype($post) == 'post') {
return $permalink;
}
switch ($post->post_type) {
case 'post':
    //$permalink = get_home_url() . '/' . $post->post_name . '/';

    $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $subcats = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        $cat = get_category($cat->term_id);
        if($cat->parent) { $subcats[] = sanitize_title($cat->name); }
    }
    if($subcats) {
        foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
            $subcat = $subcat.'/';
            $permalink = str_replace($subcat, "", $permalink);
        }
    }


    break;
}

return $permalink;}
```

It's working fine but there is still a little problem with the code.

If I have an URL like this:

> www.myblog.com/parentcategory/**nameofchildcategory**/slugpost

I will get this:

> www.myblog.com/parentcategory/slugpost

Which is exactly what I want.

But if I have an URL like this:

> www.myblog.com/parentcategory/**nameofchildcategory**/slugpost-with-**nameofchildcategory**

I will get this:

> www.myblog.com/parentcategory/slugpost-with-    *(mssing the end of the slug)*

...and a 404 page for every link to this article.

So the problem is that when the child category text appears in the slug's post, the code will also remove this part of the URL.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delimiting both ends of the slug, like:

```
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            $permalink = str_replace('/'.$subcat.'/', '/', $permalink);
        }
```

Comment: Replacing with this code also removes the parent category "blogue"

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution, adding two functions. I'm not sure the code is optimal but it works perfectly.

```
add_filter('post_link','custom_post_type_link',10,3); 

//function to see if URL ends with...
function endsWith($string, $endString) { 
$len = strlen($endString); 
if ($len == 0) { 
    return true; 
} 
return (substr($string, -$len) === $endString); 
} 

//function to replace only first match
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $content)
{
$from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';

return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}

function custom_post_type_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
if (!gettype($post) == 'post') {
return $permalink;
}


switch ($post->post_type) {
case 'post':
    //$permalink = get_home_url() . '/' . $post->post_name . '/';


    $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $subcats = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        $cat = get_category($cat->term_id);
        if($cat->parent) { $subcats[] = sanitize_title($cat->name); }
    }

    if($subcats) {
        foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
            $subcat = $subcat.'/';

            //If URL ends with category name
            if(endsWith($permalink,$subcat)){
              //And if the category name appears more than once
              if(substr_count($permalink,$subcat)>1){
                // Remove only first match
                $permalink = str_replace_first($subcat, "", $permalink);
              }else{
                //do nothing
              }
            }
            // If URL does NOT end with category name
            else{
              $permalink = str_replace($subcat, "", $permalink);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}

return $permalink;}
```